# Show only half page content until user logs in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm building a page on PHP+HTML, and wondering if there's a best way to realize the following effects:

Show only half the content of the page, until the user logs in through ajax.

Example: the original page content

```
<p>1<p>
<p>2<p>
<p>3<p>
<p>4<p>
```

before the user logs in, the page would show:

```
<p>1<p>
<p>2<p>
<input>let's login to see the whole thing</input>
```

after the user logs in, the page would show:

```
<p>1<p>
<p>2<p>
<p>3<p>
<p>4<p>
```

Would appreciate any advice on the best practice!

Answer (score 0):

Hide the part you want while user not logged. Then show it.

```
<p>1<p>
<p>2<p>
<div id='logged' <?php if ($logged) echo "style='display:none;'"; ?>>
  <p>3<p>
  <p>4<p>
</div>

$.ajax({
   // log data
   success: function(){
      $('#logged').show();
   }
})
```